# Web Audio API: noteOn after noteOff not working?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I wrote a simple web app using the Web Audio API, but I've noticed that when I issue a `noteOn(0)` command to a given source, followed by a `noteOff(0)`, and then finally by another `noteOn(0)` command, the sound will turn on, turn off (as expected) but then won't turn on with the third command.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? It's as simple as that, I can show you code but I feel it's redundant. Perhaps I need to reassign the buffer to the source after the `noteOff`, but I can't imagine that's how it was intended to be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AudioBufferSourceNode can only be played once.

http://youtu.be/hFsCG7v9Y4c?t=18m22s

Answer (score 2):

Reading here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/, and specifically here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/js/volume-sample.js, it looks like resetting the source/buffer after noteOff is the way to go. I switched that up and things are working great.

Answer (score 1):

Working example code using **.disconnect()** with oscillator

http://en.wikiaudio.org/Web_Audio_API:Toggle_oscillator_on_and_off